# Compress the DataFrame based on one column

Tags: pandas

How to transform the DataFrame from

```
   l  x  y  z
0  a  1  0  0
1  a  0  1  0
2  a  0  0  1
3  b  1  0  0
4  b  0  0  1
```

to

```
   l  x  y  z
0  a  1  1  1
1  b  1  0  1
```

for each unique value in column `l`, compress the other column's value into 0 or 1.
values for `x, y, z` is either 1 or 0.

The original DataFrame has the property: for each unique of `l`, `x, y` or `z` only has one `1`  at most.

Comment: Use `df = df.groupby('l', as_index=False).max()`

Comment: Or `df2.groupby('l').agg('sum')`